# Environment setup for performance tests involving multiple JVM

Tags: performance, jvm, benchmarking

I am planning to conduct a performance test of certain aop framework based aspects on one of my web application deployed on tomcat . The aspects are applied on most of the method calls and will incur some overhead . I plan to measure the CPU and JVM stats during my tests along with the response time and throughput stats . For generating the load on the webapp i m planning to use  Jmeter . MY question is whether i should have the entire setup (tomcat+jmeter ) on a single machine or they should be on different machines ? . Since both tomcat and Jmeter will have their own JVM's , i don't want the performance stats of appserver to get affected due to the resources consumed by Jmeter .  I plan to use JMX for JVM stats measurement and some proprietary api for CPU measurement (at process level ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tomcat and Jmeter on  different machines and the stats seem to report without much issues with regards to accuracy .